# pySerial and SimpleXMLRPCServer: why does serial.write() work but serial.read() not?

Tags: python, pyserial

I tried to communicate from my computer with the serial port of Raspberry Pi over a XMLRPC server. I am wondering that writing to serial port works but reading did not work, read() function shows a timeout. I verified with an oscilloscope that data is send and received through the serial port. Any hints to solve this issue?

XMLRCP Server Code:

```
import socket
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler
import serial

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ipaddress = [(s.connect(('8.8.8.8', 53)), s.getsockname()[0], s.close()) for s in [socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)]][0][1]
    port = 8000
    server = SimpleXMLRPCServer((ipaddress, port), requestHandler=SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler, allow_none=True)
    server.register_introspection_functions()
    server.register_instance(serial.Serial("/dev/serial0", 57600, timeout=1.0))
    print("Server running on {}:{}".format(ipaddress, port))
    server.serve_forever()
```

XMLRPC Client Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import xmlrpclib

config = {
    "ipaddress": "172.25.125.235",
    "port": 8000
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'http://{ipaddress}:{port}'.format(**config)
    print("Connecting to {}".format(url))
    iface = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(url, allow_none=True)
    print(iface.system.listMethods())
    print(iface.write("d1234" + chr(13)))
    print(repr(iface.read()))
```

Output from client:

```
Connecting to http://172.25.125.235:8000
['applySettingsDict', 'apply_settings', 'cancel_read', 'cancel_write', 'close',
'fileno', 'flush', 'flushInput', 'flushOutput', 'getCD', 'getCTS', 'getDSR', 'ge
tRI', 'getSettingsDict', 'get_settings', 'inWaiting', 'iread_until', 'isOpen', '
isatty', 'next', 'nonblocking', 'open', 'read', 'read_all', 'read_until', 'reada
ble', 'readall', 'readinto', 'readline', 'readlines', 'reset_input_buffer', 'res
et_output_buffer', 'seek', 'seekable', 'sendBreak', 'send_break', 'setDTR', 'set
Port', 'setRTS', 'set_input_flow_control', 'set_output_flow_control', 'system.li
stMethods', 'system.methodHelp', 'system.methodSignature', 'tell', 'truncate', '
writable', 'write', 'writelines']
6
''
```